# I have bags 2 and 3 labeled 719R6… Which set are they from?

Tags: set-identification, piece-information, friends

They are likely from the Lego Friends series, since those sets are what my daughter likes. Lots of lavender, aqua, white and grey pieces. 719R6 on both bags.

Googling it turns up a Star Wars set 7196, which it is not.

Comment: Hi LegoMom9111111 and welcome to Bricks.SE! The codes printed on the bags are unfortunately only there to identify the empty plastic bags during the packaging process - they bear no information about the contents once sealed. Can you perhaps upload a photo with as much of the contained pieces visible as possible? Or check out the linked Q&A page on how to identify the set and get back to edit this question if you get stuck. Good luck and play well!